# Grizzly2 Server combine Jersey & Comet

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey, comet

I have a small question: Is there a chance to combine the jersey and the comet framework together in one project? Does anyone have an example?

Actual projcet:
I created a maven project in eclipse with the architype: jersey-quickstart-grizzly2. Jersey und Grizzly2 works like charm with the helloWorld Application from the Jersey examples (SSL is enabled). See code below.

Now I'm wondering how I can add a Comet Servlet, Comet Context, etc.?

```
public class Main {
    // Base URI the Grizzly HTTP server will listen on
    public static final String BASE_URI = "https://localhost:8081/myapp/";
    private static String KEYSTORE_PATH = "";
    private static String KEYSTORE_PASS = "";



    /**
     * Starts Grizzly HTTP server exposing JAX-RS resources defined in this application.
     * @return Grizzly HTTP server.
     */
    public static HttpServer startServer() {



        System.out.println(UtilProperties.getInstance().loadProperty("url"));

        // create a resource config that scans for JAX-RS resources and providers
        final ResourceConfig rc = new ResourceConfig().packages("com.yes.httpremoteserver.HTTPRemoteServer");

        // Grizzly ssl configuration
        SSLContextConfigurator sslContext = new SSLContextConfigurator();


        sslContext.setKeyStoreFile(KEYSTORE_PATH); // contains server keypair           
        sslContext.setKeyStorePass(KEYSTORE_PASS);

        // create and start a new instance of grizzly http server
        // exposing the Jersey application at BASE_URI
        return GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer(
                URI.create(BASE_URI), 
                rc, 
                true, 
                new SSLEngineConfigurator(sslContext).setClientMode(false).setNeedClientAuth(false));


    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     * @param args
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        KEYSTORE_PATH = args[0];
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println(args[1]);
        KEYSTORE_PASS = args[1];



        final HttpServer server = startServer();



        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
                + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();    
        server.shutdown();
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your responses!

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/BangBoy/Grizzly-Jersey-Spring-Spring-Security

this URL uses spring..but also shows how to integrate Jersey & Comet into a Grizzly server.